# XML parsing - How to add child elements to an Array list using for loop

Tags: java, xml, for-loop, arraylist, xml-parsing

I am struggling with a `for` loop condition which can add all `xml` child elements in to an `ArrayList`. I can add each and every child node without using loop like below

```
testData.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("server").item(0).getTextContent());
```

I am confused on how to add all elements using a for loop. Here is my test code:

```
ArrayList<String> testData = null;
        testData = new ArrayList<>();
        File fXmlFile = new File("C://Javaseleniumworld/soemthing.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                testData.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("server").item(0).getTextContent());
                testData.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("username").item(0).getTextContent());
                testData.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("password").item(0).getTextContent());
                testData.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                testData.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("dobmm").item(0).getTextContent());
                testData.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("dobdd").item(0).getTextContent());
                testData.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("dobyyyy").item(0).getTextContent());
```

Comment: Under Staff for all childs this code  is adding the text value in the list

Comment: **We** are confused by the lack of a clear question from your side. You're code is already adding elements to the list, isn't it? What else do you need it to do?

Comment: i need to add elements in a loop without getting elements by tagname..I am pretty close but confused on how to loop thru all child elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `staff` elements contain only child elements with no further nested elements the easiest way to access all those child elements is doing

```
NodeList childEls = eElement.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

then you can loop through that `NodeList` and add the `getTextContent()` of each element to your `ArrayList`.

Or you need to process `eElement.getChildNodes()` and make sure you only add element nodes to your list by checking 'getNodeType()` on each node in the child nodes collection.

Answer (score 0):

as Martin has told you can do like following:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");  
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {  
// Do something with the element here  like add element in arraylist
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am finally able to parse an XML and drive my selenium script with that data.